# Third party library troubles on LayerType attribute even after building it on Android 3.2

Tags: android, android-library

So, I coded my entire app in Android 4.0.3.  I used [AmbilWarna](http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/) color picker.  Then I got this requirement to reduce the SDK requirement for Android 2.3.  This is the point when EVERYTHING was working fine and superb

I have downgraded teh minimum SDK requirement. Everything runs fine except as soon as I include Ambil Warna as a library on my project, I start getting the error everywhere R is used, Saying that R cannot be resolved to a variable.

Upon a loot on the Console, this is what seems to be the real cause of the problem:

```
AmbilWarna\res\layout\ambilwarna_dialog.xml:18: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layerType' in package 'android'
```

I have set the Android SDK to 3.2 for AmbilWarna library project and on my project its at 2.3

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you post ambilwarna_dialog.xml?

Comment: @yorkw http://code.google.com/p/yuku-android-util/source/browse/AmbilWarna/res/layout-land/ambilwarna_dialog.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is regarding this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layerType

you are just trying to use a property for `android` that is not available on that api of the layout parser.

I just checked out the colorpicker code you are trying to use, and it's project.properties says it's written for target API-17 (android 4.2) and i'm tryng to compile it for API-10 (android 2.3.3)

simply remove those parts.

my diff

```
--- a/AmbilWarna/res/layout/ambilwarna_dialog.xml
+++ b/AmbilWarna/res/layout/ambilwarna_dialog.xml
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@
             android:id="@+id/ambilwarna_viewSatBri"
             android:layout_width="@dimen/ambilwarna_hsvWidth"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/ambilwarna_hsvHeight"
-            android:layerType="software" />
+        />
```

and hope it's not mentioned in the code :)

Comment: Is it possible to have the layerType value be set in the resources, so that it will be different across different Android versions?

Comment: @androiddeveloper good question. I am actually an amateur on android development and always found supporting older versions (that are still widely used!) very difficult!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of troubles too with my external libraries. What usually helped are **one of these or multiple steps of these** connected:

1. Delete **ALL** R.java imports in your Classes (there must not be any of them)
2. In Eclipse: Source => "Clean Up"
3. In Eclipse: Project => "Clean..." (This will rebuild your project from scratch and therefore regenerate your R.java)
4. Manually delete all R.java and save (located in /gen/)
5. Delete your external library project and readd it.

Step 3 usually did the job for me.
Also be aware that your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion fit to your library project (and the guidelines which are included)

Comment: people nowadays relying on IDE instead of understanding what is going on. Remember the hacker jargon file: `A novice was trying to fix a broken Lisp machine by turning the power off and on.` `Knight, seeing what the student was doing, spoke sternly: “You cannot fix a machine by just power-cycling it with no understanding of what is going wrong.”``Knight turned the machine off and on.``The machine worked.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I thought I could just build and include the third party jar file and bring this over to my project - this resulted in the same problem as you - AmbilWarna\res\layout\ambilwarna_dialog.xml error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layerType'.

To fix it I copied over the source files and all resources into my project (images/layouts etc etc), hey presto it worked.

Thanks http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/ for a nice clean easy to use colour picker!!